# Django: How can I update my database using an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, database

In my web app., I have users who have a coin balance in addition to a timer. When the timer finishes counting down, I would like for their coin balance to increase.

Within Django, I access the user's coin balance using:
`{{ request.user.profile.coins }}`, and my JS timer looks like this:

```
function startClock () {
timeInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var t = getTimeLeft(deadline);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) { 
        clearInterval(timeInterval);

if (i === 7) {
  $(".reset, .start-pomodoro").addClass('hidden');
  $(".start-break2").removeClass('hidden');
}

        else if ((i % 2) === 1) {
          $(".reset, .start-pomodoro").addClass('hidden');
  $(".start-break1").removeClass('hidden');
        }

        else {
  $(".start-pomodoro").removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

How can I make it so that before the if statement executes, the user's coin balance increases?

Comment: Make call to server requesting to increase the coin ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that or what I'd need to learn

Comment: What you need to learn is ajax

Comment: @e4c5 I think OP knows about JS and wants to update the Django database. Is that right ?

Comment: Since you are using JQuery, I suggest you to read `$.ajax` function. You can then create a view that increases the coin balance and call this view asynchronously (ie. without refreshing the page) using ajax.

Comment: you got that @RajaSimon the user seems to know jquery but does he know ajax? This question woudl not have been posted if the answer is yes

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for @Selcuk, I'll look into it!

Comment: @e4c5 I just read the Selcuk answer. He's showing the right direction. Can you gone through it. Let us know when you are trouble.

Comment: Can you check my attempt below @Selcuk?

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required(login_url='users/login')                                                                 
    def coin_increase(request):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        user.profile.coins += 5
        user.save()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'home': home})
```

How does this look?

Comment: Please don't post new questions as answers, but update your original question instead. If you tested this and it worked, go for it. As a side note, you don't need to (and it won't work anyway if you simply discard the result in your JQuery code) return a template from ajax views. A simple `HttpResponse` would suffice.